# Review queue count not correct

Tags: bug, review-queues

For the past one week, I notice an issue in the review queue count in stackoverflow. In the review queue summary page, it is showing some count and when I open particular review task, it is not showing any posts to be reviewed. Please check the screenshots given below:

#### Review Summary Page:

[image]

#### Suggested Edits Review Page:

[image]

In the summary page, it showed 7 edits to be reviewed. But in review page, it showed no edits to be reviewed. Why this is happening?