# How do the review queue works?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I'm recently working on the review section.

And I notice that not every time it has review posts for me.

But when I'm working on it, I found some questions I don't quite understand:

1. Usually, when the number is positive for the queue, I click to enter, there is no review tips for me.
2. The actual post count for that queue doesn't match what I can actually deal with. For example, I see 6 posts in the `First Posts` queue, then I entered, but seeing nothing for me.
3. When I'm dealing with a post, but maybe taking time a bit longer, when I'm about to take an action, the `I'm Done` button is disabled, and I can only click `Next`.

So I'm wondering how do the review queue works? Can multiple user can access one single post at the same time, and wondering if the queue count number changes too fast, and losing its meaning?

Comment: The numbers are cached, so their values aren't accurate. They refresh periodically.

Comment: @Infinite Recursion: yes, I think it does. But actually the number is usually zero, and I think it's meaningless.

Comment: I agree to the numbers being meaningless, however there are valid reasons behind the current behavior. You can [read this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266182/review-queue-count-not-correct). The zero is because lots of reviewers actively participate in reviewing.